# How to add files to ipfs using ingress url from the command line tool - ipfs-cluster-ctl?

Tags: command-line, kubernetes, haproxy

I have deployed ipfs-cluster as a statefulset with 3 replicas in Azure Kubernetes cluster. Created loadbalancer service for ipfs and used the loadbalancer service ip to add files using ipfs-cluster-ctl like below,

```
ipfs-cluster-ctl --host /ip4/20.94.98.25/tcp/9094 add test.txt
```

The above command provides CID as an output. Sample output looks like,

```
added Qmeeyj7hldjsj9XCoLSK6dY7ZTVTt8YcjfHXAuTzhCrz test.txt
```

Now, I have created ingress using haproxy for the ipfs-cluster service and tried to access the added files using the ingress url, sample url looks like,

`http://ipfs.testing.example.com/ipfs/Qmeeyj7hldjsj9XCoLSK6dY7ZTVTt8YcjfHXAuTzhCrz`

The above url works fine and showing the file content of test.txt

But now I need to use the ingress url instead of loadbalancer ip to add files using ipfs-cluster-ctl. I don't find any reference to achieve this. Can anyone please guide me to add files to ipfs using ingress url.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu v20.04